# bluebird 3.1.1 Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, promise, bluebird

I have the following code taken from http://passportjs.org/docs/configure and since updating to bluebird:3.1.1 i keep getting the http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-none-were-returned-from-it

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  return User.findByIdOrThrowPr(id, 'company').then(function(user) {
    return done(null, user);
  })['catch'](function(err) {
    return done(err, null);
  });
});
```

which gives these warnings

```
Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it
  at setViewLocals (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/app/app.coffee:96:11)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at trim_prefix (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
  at Function.process_params (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
  at next (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/i18next/lib/i18next.js:119:13
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/i18next/node_modules/i18next-client/i18next.js:992:21
  at Object.i18n.functions.extend.load (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/i18next/lib/i18nextWrapper.js:326:17)
  at init (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/i18next/node_modules/i18next-client/i18next.js:988:19)
  at Object.setLng (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/i18next/node_modules/i18next-client/i18next.js:1200:16)
  at i18n.handle (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/i18next/lib/i18next.js:117:14)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at trim_prefix (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
  at Function.process_params (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
  at next (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
  at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:325:9)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/passport/lib/strategies/session.js:65:12
  at pass (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:327:31)
  at deserialized (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:339:7)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/app/authentication/index.coffee:43:5
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
From previous event:
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/app/authentication/index.coffee:42:41
  at pass (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:347:9)
  at Authenticator.deserializeUser (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:352:5)
  at SessionStrategy.authenticate (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/passport/lib/strategies/session.js:53:28)
  at attempt (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:348:16)
  at authenticate (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:349:7)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at trim_prefix (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
  at Function.process_params (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
  at next (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
  at initialize (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/initialize.js:53:5)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at trim_prefix (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
  at Function.process_params (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
  at next (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/app/translation.coffee:43:5
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at trim_prefix (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
  at Function.process_params (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
  at next (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/connect-flash/lib/flash.js:21:5
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at trim_prefix (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
  at Function.process_params (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
  at next (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express-device/lib/device.js:46:26
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at trim_prefix (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
  at Function.process_params (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
  at next (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
  at csrf (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/csurf/index.js:100:5)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at trim_prefix (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
  at Function.process_params (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
  at next (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
  at /home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/express-session/index.js:432:7
  at Command.callback (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/connect-redis/lib/connect-redis.js:148:14)
  at RedisClient.return_reply (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/redis/index.js:664:25)
  at JavascriptReplyParser.reply_parser.send_reply (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/redis/index.js:332:14)
  at JavascriptReplyParser.run (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/redis/lib/parsers/javascript.js:132:18)
  at JavascriptReplyParser.execute (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/redis/lib/parsers/javascript.js:107:10)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/khine/Sandboxes/node-blade-boiler-template/node_modules/redis/index.js:131:27)
  at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

app/app.coffee

```
setViewLocals = (req, res, next) ->

  cartUserId = null
  #shopForUserId = null
  if req.isAuthenticated()
    if req.user.isStaff()
      cartUserId = req.user.shopFor
      #shopForUserId = req.user.shopFor
    else
      cartUserId = req.user._id
  Promise.resolve()
    .then -> if cartUserId then M.Cart.setActive(cartUserId)
    .then ->
      Promise.props
        collections: M.Collection.findUsedCachedPr()
        logos: M.Logos.findAllPr()
        categories: M.Category.findUsedCachedPr()
        affiliations: M.Affiliation.findAllPr()
        cart: cartUserId and M.Cart.findByIdOrNewPr(cartUserId)
        articles: M.Article.getUsedCategoriesPr()
        shopForUser: cartUserId and M.User.findByIdOrNull(cartUserId, ["company"])
        userDiscounts: adminRules.getRules(req.user)
        maintenance: M.Maintenance.underMaintenance()
        #userNotifications: M.Notification.getNotifications(req.user)
    .then (result) ->
      req.cartUser = result.shopForUser or req.user
      req.tt = translation.translateDbString
      req.tCountryNames = countries.getCountryNames
      affiliations = _(result.affiliations).sortBy('position').value()
      res.redirectWithFlash = redirectWithFlash
      _.extend res.locals,
        discountAvailable: Object.keys(result.userDiscounts).length > 0
        angularApp: false
        messages: req.flash()
        _csrf: req.csrfToken()
        user: req.user
        tt: translation.translateDbString
        menuCollections: result.collections
        logos: result.logos
        menuCategories: result.categories
        affiliations: affiliations
        articles: result.articles
        menuCart: result.cart
        shopForUser: result.shopForUser
        userDiscounts: result.userDiscounts
        maintenance: result.maintenance
        __collectionId: req.query.collectionId or ''
        __categoryId: req.query.categoryId or ''
        __color: req.query.color or ''
        _: _
        tCountryNames: countries.getCountryNames
        tCountry: countries.getCountryName
        allowedUrls: req.allowedUrls = adminUser.getAllowedUrls req.user
        currentYear: moment().format('YYYY')
        settings: res.locals.settings or {} # WTF?
        curLang: req.i18n.lng()
      _.extend res.locals.settings, __settings, assetsSettings
      null
    .asCallback next
```

any advice, much appreciated

Comment: What's at line 96 of `app/app.coffee`? The traceback seems to suggest that that is the location where the promise is created.

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: What that error message means is that inside a `.then()` handler your code is creating a new promise, but not returning it and thus it is orphaned and the outer promises do not synchronize with it.  There are some circumstances where that's the intended behavior, but usually not - thus the warning.  I don't know coffeescript to know where that is happening in your code or whether it's an actual issue in your code or just a warning to ignore.